# Python MySQL: cursor.excute(query,args) fails while cursor.execute(query) passes for the same query

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

I have a python function that gets me version info like this:

```
def get_version_info(build_id, table_name='build_info'):
    query = "SELECT `build_commit` FROM `" + table_name + "`  WHERE `build_id` = %s "
    args = (build_id)
    #query = "SELECT `build_commit` FROM `" + table_name + "`  WHERE `build_id` = " + build_id
    build_commit = None
    try:
        dbconfig = read_db_config()
        conn = MySQLConnection(**dbconfig)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query, args)
        #cursor.execute(query)
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        if row is not None:
           build_commit = row[0]
```

This functions always returns `None` no matter what. 
And when I change this to use non-parameterized query like below. It always returns correct `build_commit`.

```
def get_version_info(build_id, table_name='build_info'):
    query = "SELECT `build_commit` FROM `" + table_name + "`  WHERE `build_id` = " + build_id
    ...
    cursor.execute(query)
```

Is there something, I am missing out in the parameterized query for cursor.execute which is why it is failing.

Comment: You can't user parameters for table names. And the only way that that query would return None is if you were catching and swallowing the error that would otherwise have told you what was doing wrong. Don't do that.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Even if I change the query to receive the table name as is (updated question code). I still am getting None. And I am raising any kind of error in try catch. So how would any error would get swallowed up?

Comment: `args` should be a tuple: `args = (build_id,)`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You have a try; you don't show the except but I guess you are just blindly catching every exception. So doing that and let Python tell you what is wrong.